# How to send nested params to axios and receive on server

Tags: javascript, axios

How can i send a nested obj of params to axios and receive them on the server side?

```
const params = JSON.stringify({
  sizes: {
    thumb: [400, 400],
    banner: [1280, 400],
  },
});
const res = await api({
  method: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:3000/v1/api/create",
  params: params,
});
```

On the express server i have

**create.js**

```
module.exports = async function (req, res) {
...
console.log(req.query)
console.log(JSON.parse(req.query))
}
```

I get errors though

```
{ '0': '{"sizes":{"thumb":[400,400],"banner":[1280,400]}}' }
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Am i passing them or receiving them incorrectly?

console print of req.query

```
...
{ '0': '{"sizes":{"thumb":[400,400],"banner":[1280,400]}}' }
...
```

Comment: Can you share the console.log of req.query?

Comment: sure, i updated post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think is happening is that your frontend and server are serializing and de-serializing nested queries differently.

Using the same serialization/de-serialzation function will solve the problem.

Here's an example with the ["qs" library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs):

Frontend:

```
const qs = require('qs')

// don't stringify it, let the library do it for you
const params = {
  sizes: {
    thumb: [400, 400],
    banner: [1280, 400],
  },
};
const res = await api({
  method: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:3000/v1/api/create",
  params: params,
  paramsSerializer: qs.stringify
})
```

Server:

```
const express = require('express')
const qs = require('qs')

// be sure to define this first
app.set('query parser', str => qs.parse(str))

// then define your routes
app.get("/", (req, res) => console.log(req.query))
```

Comment: Ah yes the solution of all js developers... add a library!

Comment: every js problem requires a js solution 

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `req.query` is already an object, that is why `JSON.parse` fails. The '0' property of `req.query` is your stringified object. So that is the part you want to parse.

```js
let object = JSON.parse(req.query['0']);
```

Now object will be

```json
{
  sizes: {
    thumb: [400, 400],
    banner: [1280, 400],
  }
}
```